# WiX3 to WiX4 installer - problems updating

Tags: wix, wix3, wix4

I have an application, which used to use wix3 .msi package for installing. I have updated wix version to 4.0.4 and now I am experiencing issues.
Everything works fine if I freshly install app with wix4 .msi package. Also updating this app works as it should.

PROBLEM:
If I have an app installed with wix3 .msi package and I want to update it with wix4 .msi package the installation procedure looks normal. But the when I first launch the app the .msi configuring window pops up and after that the app is fully installed. Before that seems like not all dlls are installed correctly.

I have tried different update options:
This is the original code:

```
<Upgrade Id="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx">
<UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="99.0.0.0" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="yes" />
</Upgrade>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Then I have added `OnlyDetect="no"` option.
Also tried `<RemoveExistingProducts Before:"InstallInitialize"/>`

I have tried removing above code, replacing it with MajorUpgrade element (which by default uses `Schedule="afterInstallValidate"`).

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of bOS Server is already installed." 
                      AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"/>
```

None of these produces desired result.
For now the only thing that works is manual uninstall and then install of a new version.

Have someone experienced similar problems?

Comment: Did you modify the ProductCode in latest version of msi?